# Adding metadata to PDF

Tags: ruby, pdf, pdf-generation, metadata, prawn

I need to add metadata to a PDF which I am creating using [prawn](http://rubygems.org/gems/prawn).  That meta-data will be extracted later by, probably, [pdf-reader](http://rubygems.org/gems/pdf-reader).  This metadata will contain internal document numbers and other information needed by downstream tools.

It would be convenient to associate meta-data with each page of the PDF.  [The PDF specification](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) claims that I can store per-page private data in a "Page-Piece Dictionary".  Section 14.5 states:

> A page-piece dictionary (PDF 1.3) may be used to hold private
>   conforming product data. The data may be associated with a page or
>   form XObject by means of the optional PieceInfo entry in the page
>   object (see Table 30) or form dictionary (see Table 95). Beginning
>   with PDF 1.4, private data may also be associated with the PDF
>   document by means of the PieceInfo entry in the document catalogue
>   (see Table 28).

How can I set a "page-piece dictionary" with prawn?  I'm using prawn 0.12.0.

If that's not possible, how else can I achieve my goal of storing metadata about each page, either at the page level, or at the document level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to do *none of the above*; that is, don't attach the metadata as a page-piece dictionary, and don't attach it with prawn.  Instead, attach the metadata as a file attachment using the [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) command-line tool.

To do it this way, create a file with the metadata.  For example, the file *metadata.yaml* might contain:

```
---
- :document_id: '12345'
  :account_id: 10
  :page_numbers:
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
- :document_id: '12346'
  :account_id: 24
  :page_numbers:
  - 4
```

After you are done creating the pdf file with prawn, then use *pdftk* to attach the metadata file to the pdf file:

```
$ pdftk foo.pdf attach_files metadata.yaml output foo-with-attachment.pdf
```

Since *pdftk* will not modify a file in place, the output file must be different than the input file.

You may be able to extract the metadata file using pdf-reader, but you can certainly do it with pdftk.  This command unpacks *metadata.yaml* into the *unpacked-attachments* directory.

```
$ pdftk foo-with-attachment.pdf unpack_files output unpacked-attachments
```

Answer (score 7):

you can look at the source of prawn

https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/commit/131082af5abb71d83de0e2005ecceaa829224904

```
info = { :Title => "Sample METADATA",
             :Author => "Me",
             :Subject => "Not Working",
             :CreationDate => Time.now }

@pdf = Prawn::Document.new(:template => filename, :info => info)
```

Comment: Is the PDF header an appropriate place for large, private metadata?  Especially, is a PDF with private keys in the PDF header compliant?

Comment: I am not sure for large data, but if you want all the info about the file that is the place where it should go. do you have a example of the data that you want to save?

Comment: If expressed in YAML, the metadata could be tens of thousands of lines for one PDF.